# The member role cannot find the deletion information of db

Tags: cnosdb

The member role cannot find the deletion information of db
version:cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 2fd7e8d02516beb696472d9bee115d948c224d1c
mode: 3m2d

```
To Reproduce

start 3m2d cluster;

create tenant, t001;

create database db001 in t001;

create user u001, add tenant t001 as member;

root: drop db001;

u001: select * from information_schema.resource_status; (there is nothing)
```

Expected behavior

No response

Additional context

No response